# connect to quickbooks, refresh app

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

In my app I have the 'Connect To QuickBooks' button that works as it should. When it is clicked it opens a window that allows the user to sigh in to their company. My problem is that I need to refresh my app to show the new information (Company name, etc), but I have not been able to find a way to refresh my app from the OauthHandler.aspx, that is opened in another browser window, by the 'Connect To QuickBooks' call. I must not be understanding something, can anybody help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in OauthHandler.aspx-
My refreshed page is default.aspx. Please set the page you want for your application.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    try {

        var parentlocation = window.parent.opener.location.hostname;
        var currentlocation = window.location.hostname;
        if (parentlocation != currentlocation) {

            window.location = "/default.aspx";
        }
        else {

            window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

            window.close();
        }
    }
    catch (e) {

        window.location = "/default.aspx";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately it didn't work. The first line throws and error (undefined error). The 'window.location' does hit my app page, but it only runs the code behind code and doesn't refresh the page. F5 refreshed the page.

Comment: Please check the sample app for v3 to see how this works-https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-DotNet